# What is the correct way to deal with a quantity of gravity in science fiction?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to edit someone's sci-fi novel, and I'm running into a need to refer to **levels of gravity in a space station and on other planets in terms of Earth gravity**. I cannot find a correct standard for this. Would it be 0.3 g? 0.3 G? 0.3 Gs? 0.3 G's?

And generally it's desirable to spell out units of measure in fiction, I think, but that doesn't really work here, does it? "A third of Earth's gravity" is a fine workaround when it's seldom needed, but when the concept comes up a lot, the correct unit is necessary.

I have had no luck Googling this; believe me, I tried. I'm not even sure if conceptually what I'm dealing with is G (Newton's gravitational constant) or g-force. I have seen both "g" and "G's" used in various places, but what I'm looking for is the **accepted standard for use in science fiction novels**.

EDIT: For clarity's sake, I should mention that almost all the main characters are humans from Earth or space stations near Earth, so the perspective is based on Earth gravity.

Comment: The accepted standard for use in science fiction novels written on Telus of Sol or Velantia? Modelled on _zero-g_, I'd expect 'a 3-g planet', as found in Smith's and Goldin's writings, to be totally acceptable (what would 3-G mean? g is the acceleration due to gravity at the Earth's surface, whereas G is the universal gravitational constant.) But do you really expect SF writers, of all people, to accept literary constraints?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So we're looking at, for instance, scenes involving people moving from one place to another on a spinning space station, like, "...passing from Deck A at 0.3 g to Deck Z at a full 'g' would..." I'm totally at a loss.

Comment: Keep in mind that "g" references Earth's gravity.  There's no reason to expect residents of the planet Adhoc to use the same term or numbers on the same scale.

Comment: @Hot Licks And chocolate chip cookies (even the best of them) are probably deadly poisonous to Adhocians.

Comment: In the d'Alembert series, mention is made of 'three gravities' (meaning the acceleration due to gravity on that world / that deck of the ship is / is set at 30m/s/s).

Comment: @HotLicks Edited for clarity; everything is from an "Earth human" perspective.

Comment: Keep in mind that someone in the future might choose to restate gravitational measurements in terms of acceleration -- meters per second squared, or whatever.  Earth's gravity is 9.80665 m/s/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might require you to embed some explanation up front, but, for levels of gravity in the space station (or other such spacecraft), you could leverage the term **micro-g** (or *µ*g).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-g_environment) says:

> The term **micro-g environment** is more or less a synonym of weightlessness and zero-g, but indicates that g-forces are not quite zero, just very small.

As for the gravitational forces on other planets, I don't know if there's a "standard" convention, but you could easily devise your own early in the work, and stick with it from there. For example:

> *Special gravity boots were standard issue on this mission. Xerov was a .3G planet, so Ted would weigh less than one-third of his normal body weight after they landed*.

I think most sci-fi fans would be able to put two and two together with an introduction like that.